# python to php code conversion

Tags: php, python, converters

I have to translate two Python functions into PHP. The first one is:

```
def listspaces(string):
        return [i -1 for i in range(len(string)) if string.startswith(' ', i-1)]
```

I am assuming that this will check for space in provided string and return True when first occurrence of space is found, is this correct ?

What is `i-1` here ? is it `-1` ?

In PHP we use `[]` for arrays . Here we are `[]` with return, will this function return true or false or array of locations of spaces ?

Second function is

```
def trimcopy(copy, spaces, length=350):

    try:
        if len(copy) < length:
            return copy
        else:
            loc = 0
            for space in spaces:
                if space < length:
                    loc = space
                else:
                    return copy[:loc]
    except :
        return None
```

Whats for space in spaces: here and whats is this  `return copy[:loc]`

Comment: check python list comprehension, for loops and python slicing....

Comment: these are quite bizarre functions (`trimcopy` especially)!

Comment: I comeup  with this as php alternate for both functions

list($short) = explode("\n",wordwrap($string,100));
is this correct ?

Comment: That doesn't quite do it, try this bit inside the else block in trimcopy: list($newtext) = explode(" ",wordwrap($string,350," "));, however it is difficult to tell what the function intends (as it's surely buggy)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may notice that the first function could also have been written as

```
def listspaces(str):
    return [i for i, c in enumerate(str) if c==' ']
```

That version has the following straightforward conversion to PHP:

```
function listspaces($str) {
    $spaces = array();

    foreach (str_split($str) as $i => $chr)
        if ($chr == ' ') $spaces[] = $i;

    return $spaces;
}
```

As for the other function, this seems to do the same thing in very nearly the same idiom:

```
function trimcopy($copy, $spaces, $length=350) {
    if (strlen($copy) < $length) {
        return $copy;
    } else {
        foreach ($spaces as $space) {
            if ($space < $length) {
                $loc = $space;
            } else {
                return substr($copy, 0, $loc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As others have pointed out, the intent of both of these functions could probably be better expressed by using `wordwrap`.

Comment: Thanks, do u agree with this line as alternate for these two functions

list($short) = explode("\n",wordwrap($string,350));

Comment: If they are only ever used in combination, they seem designed to do just that. For that matter, you could have used textwrap.wrap in python's standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good process for these type of conversions is:

- work out what the code is doing
- refactor it into a PHP-style in Python (this enables you to check that the logic still works, e.g. using assertion tests). e.g. convert list comprehensions to for loops
- convert to PHP

For example, `listspaces(string)` returns the positions of spaces in `string`, and although using a list comprehension is Pythonic, it's not very "PHP-onic".

```
def listspaces2(string): #PHP-onic listspaces
    space_positions = []
    for i in range(len(string))]:
        if string[i] == ' ':
            space_positions.append(i)
    return space_positions
```

The second example, `trimcopy` is rather trickier (since the try, except may purposefully be catching some expected - to the writer (!) - exceptions - two possibles are `string` not having a `len` and `spaces` containing values longer than `len(copy)`), but it's hard to say so it's a good idea to refactor in Python and test.

You can do array slicing in PHP like `copy[:loc]` using [`array_slice($copy, 0, $loc);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Note: *usually in Python we would state explicitly which exception we are defending against (as opposed to [Pokemon exception handling](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html)).*

Comment: To the `try … except`: I guess this is because it is not checked anywhere if `copy` really consists of at least `loc` chars in `copy[:loc]`.+

Comment: @feeela I guess that too... but it could be hiding some sinister bug in the rest of the code!

Comment: I comeup  with this as php alternate for both functions

list($short) = explode("\n",wordwrap($string,100));
is this correct ?

Comment: Nearly, this does **only** the bit inside the else block in trimcopy: `list($newtext) = explode(" ",wordwrap($string,350," ",true));`, although it is difficult to tell what the function intends (as it's surely buggy)!

Comment: @hayden, 
Thanks I will add this line  if (strlen($string) > 350) 
{
list($newtext) = explode(" ",wordwrap($string,350," ",true));
}

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just test those functions to see what they are doing?

`listspaces(string)` returns an array with the positions of all spaces within the string:

```
$ ipython
IPython 0.10.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: def listspaces(string):
   ...:     return [i -1 for i in range(len(string)) if string.startswith(' ', i-1)]
   ...:

In [2]: listspaces('Hallo du schöne neue Welt!')
Out[2]: [5, 8, 16, 21]
```

(`i -1` is the position of a space when starting to count with zero)

I don't know much about Python and I can't paste the second function as there are to many "IndentationError"'s.

I think that `trimcopy()` will return a string (from input `copy`), where everything behind the last space position given in the array `spaces` (obviously a return value from `listspaces()`) is trimmed, unless the input is no longer than `length`.
In other words: the input is cut off at the highest space position that is smaller than `length`.

As of the example above, the part `' Welt!'` will get cut off:

```
s = 'Hallo du schöne neue Welt!'
trimcopy( s, listspaces( s ) )
/* should return: 'Hallo du schöne neue' */
```

Comment: I tried it , first one is returning array of locations and second is not doing anything its returning same text but trimmed version

Comment: If copy is longer than length, it returns the chunk of copy before the first space, this may or may not be longer than length, this behaviour can't be good...

Comment: @hayden well, I didn't wrote those functions…

Comment: @feeela I know! But it is amusing to compare output from `'a '*100`, `'a '*200` and `'a'*400`. :)

Comment: I comeup with this as php alternate for both functions list($short) = explode("\n",wordwrap($string,100)); is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The first function returns indexes of all spaces in given string.

- `range(len(string))` [results](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html) in list with numbers from 0 to length of the input string
- `if string.startswith(' ', i-1)]` condition is evaluated for each index `i`, it returns true when string (here it is not a keyword) starts with ' ' at position given by the index `i-1`

The result is as feela posted.

For the second function I don't know what the spaces parameter is.

Hope this will help you to create a PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to both the functions in Python

```
list($short) = explode("\n",wordwrap($string,350));
```